# Diameter and distance problem in post office metric

Tags: real-analysis

I am sort of new to real analysis and I am not quite sure if I understood this question correctly.

- Find $diam A$, $diam B$ and $dist(A,B)$ in the given space X.

$A=(\frac{1}{2n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$, $B=(\frac{1}{3n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$, $X=\mathbb{R}$ with the post office metric $d(x,y) = |x|+|y|$ for $x \neq y$.

Here is my attempt:

$diam A = sup \enspace d(x,y)$

$\enspace \enspace \enspace \enspace \enspace \enspace \enspace= sup \enspace |x|+|y|$

$\enspace \enspace \enspace \enspace \enspace \enspace \enspace= sup \enspace \frac{1}{2x}+\frac{1}{2y}$

Since we are trying to find the supremum in the post office metric, I select two points that will give us the largest distance such that $x = 1$ and $y=2$ and we have $diam A = 0.75$. A similar logic would give $diam B = 0.5$.

Besides we have for the $dist(A,B)$

$dist(A,B) = inf \enspace d(x,y)$

$\enspace \enspace  \enspace  \enspace  \enspace \enspace \enspace \enspace \enspace \enspace= inf \enspace \frac{1}{2x}+\frac{1}{3y}$

Since we cannot take $x=y$ and we can take them as small as possible, we can take values such that they are close to zero. It is like taking the limit and we conclude that $dist(A,B)=0$.

Is my reasoning correct? I don't feel that I am on the right track.

Comment: Not sure why you say "we cannot take $x=y$".  Indeed, the point $\frac 16$ is in both sets $A,B$ so the distance between the sets is certainly $0$.

Comment: Well,  according to the definition of post office metric, if we take x = y, it is directly  zero. The metric is defined for points that are not the same.

Comment: Your reasoning for the diameters of $A$ and $B$ is correct, and indeed since $1/6\in A\cap B$, the distance between the sets is zero.

Comment: @studios.93 To call something post office metric and then make it not a metric wouldn't make much sense. The post office metric $d(x,y)$ is defined for **all** pairs $x,y$, even for $x=y$. Since the definition of a metric makes it clear what $d(x,x)$ has to be, this is often just not mentioned when describing a given metric.